# How to count aggregated data and create different counters?

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a data frame `df` with different columns.

```
df = data.frame(c("2012","2012","2012","2013"),
                c("AAA","BBB","AAA","AAA"),
                c("X","Not-serviced","X","Y"))
colnames(df) = c("year","type","service_type")
```

I need to get the following dataframe `df2`:

```
year    type    num_serviced   num_notserviced   num_total
2012    AAA     2              0                 2
...
```

So, I need to group data by `type` and `year`, and then to count the frequency of `Not-serviced` and the all others, e.g. `X`, `Y`, etc. (supposed as Serviced).

This is my code that calculates Total:

```
temp = aggregate(df,
                 list(type = dat_human_errors$type,
                      year = dat_human_errors$year),
                 FUN = function(x){NROW(x)})
```

However how to create `num_serviced` and `num_notserviced`? There should be some IF-THEN rule like `if type=="Not-serviced" num_notserviced++ else num_serviced++`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'year', 'type', get the `sum` of logical vectors, and finally get the total.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(num_serviced = sum(service_type != "Not-serviced"), 
      num_notserviced = sum(service_type =="Not_serviced")), 
     .(year, type)][, Total := num_serviced + num_notserviced][]
```

Comment: This works! Thanks. If I had the column `service time`and wanted to calculate the average service time corresponding to each group (i.e. row), then it would have to be done as: `avg_service_time = mean(service_time, service_type != "Not-serviced")` ?

Comment: @FiofanS  Perhaps you need `.(Mean = mean(service_time), sum(service_type != "Not-serviced"))`

Comment: `setDT(df)[, .(num_serviced = sum(service_type != "Not-serviced"), 
      num_notserviced = sum(service_type =="Not_serviced")), 
     .(year, type)][, Total := num_serviced + num_notserviced][]

Comment: Ups, doesn't allow me to edit the comment. Well ignore the previous comment please. I just wanted to confirm: `setDT(df)[, .(num_serviced = sum(service_type != "Not-serviced"), 
      num_notserviced = sum(service_type =="Not-serviced")), .(mean = mean(service_time), sum(service_type != "Not-serviced")),
     .(year, type)][, Total := num_serviced + num_notserviced][]`. It gives me error: `Provide either "by" or "keyby" but not both`.

Comment: more something like this I guess: `setDT(df)[, .(num_serviced = sum(service_type != "Not-serviced"),
              num_notserviced = sum(service_type =="Not-serviced"),
          mean = mean(service_time)),
          .(year, type)][, Total := num_serviced + num_notserviced][]
`

Comment: It then will calculate the service time over non-serviced as well (it might be negative in my case). So, I was asking about the conditioning for calculating avg_service_time only for != Not-service. Anyway, it is a new question, I will try to publish it if my reputation rank allows me to do it:)

Comment: @ FiofanS this would be a second operation i think: like: `setDT(df)[df$service_type != "Not-serviced" , .(mean = mean(service_time)),
     .(year, type)][]
`

Comment: @FiofanS Sorry, I was away with some other activity.  YOu are using multiple `.(`, why?  I meant what is the problem in using `setDT(df)[, .(num_serviced = sum(service_type != "Not-serviced"), num_notserviced = sum(service_type =="Not-serviced"), Mean = mean(service_time)), .(year, time)]`

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I tried to publish the new question but cannot do it due to Stackoverflow limits..:( The problem is that `mean(service_time)` value is related to all types: `Not serviced`, `X`, `Y` entries . But I need an average service time filtered for `X`, `Y`, etc., and the average service time - for `Not serviced` (it will be some negative value).

Comment: @FiofanS It is not completely clear to me what you wanted

Comment: Due to restrictions of Stackoverflow, I can publish the question in 90 minutes. I will post a link to this thread here. Or maybe I will be able to solve this issue myself. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40174403/how-to-calculate-average-time-for-aggregated-data-per-different-groups

Answer (score 2):

With `dplyr` you can do,

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(year,type) %>%
    summarise(num_serviced = sum(service_type != "Not-serviced"), 
              num_notserviced = sum(service_type == "Not-serviced"),
              num_total = num_serviced + num_notserviced)

#    year   type num_serviced num_notserviced num_total
#  <fctr> <fctr>        <int>           <int>     <int>
#1   2012    AAA            2               0         2
#2   2012    BBB            0               1         1
#3   2013    AAA            1               0         1
```

Answer (score 1):

the fastest way to collapse data is to use the package data.table

```
library(data.table)

df = data.frame(year = c("2012","2012","2012","2013"),
                type = c("AAA","BBB","AAA","AAA"),
                service_type= c("X","Not-serviced","X","Y"))



dt <- data.table(df)
dt<-  dt[,list(num_serviced= sum(service_type!="Not-serviced"), num_notserviced= sum(service_type=="Not-serviced")), by=c("year", "type")]
dt$num_total <- dt$num_serviced + dt$num_notserviced

#if you need to go back to dataframe:
df <- data.frame(dt)

df

  year type num_serviced num_notserviced num_total
1 2012  AAA            2               0         2
2 2012  BBB            0               1         1
3 2013  AAA            1               0         1
```