# How to calculate average time for aggregated data per different groups?

Tags: r

I have the following data frame and this question relates to [this thread]

```
df = data.frame(c("2012","2012","2012","2013"),
                c("AAA","BBB","AAA","AAA"),
                c("X","Not-serviced","X","Y"),
                c("2","10","3","2.5"))

colnames(df) = c("year","type","service_type","waiting_time")
```

I want to get average waiting times for serviced and nonserviced groups. This is how the data is grouped:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(num_serviced = sum(service_type != "Not-serviced"), 
      num_notserviced = sum(service_type =="Not_serviced"),
      avg_wt = mean(waiting_time)), ## THE PROBLEM HERE!!!
     .(year, type)][, Total := num_serviced + num_notserviced][]
```

However `avg_wt = mean(waiting_time))` estimated average waiting time over Total. I would rather need `avg_wt_serviced` and `avg_wt_notserviced`.

The result must be:

```
year  type num_serviced num_notserviced num_total avg_wt_serviced  avg_wt_notserviced
2012  AAA  2            0               2         2.5              0
```

Comment: @RonakShah: You are absolutely right. Thanks for noticing. 10 refers to 2012 and BBB. In case of 2012 and AAA it's 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `dplyr`, we can use `mean`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(year,type) %>%
   summarise(num_serviced = sum(service_type != "Not-serviced"), 
             num_notserviced = sum(service_type == "Not-serviced"),
             num_total = num_serviced + num_notserviced, 
             avg_wt_serv = mean(waiting_time[service_type != "Not-serviced"]),
             avg_wt_notser = mean(waiting_time[service_type == "Not-serviced"]))


#   year  type num_serviced num_notserviced num_total avg_wt_serv  avg_wt_notser
#   <fctr> <fctr>   <int>           <int>     <int>      <dbl>         <dbl>
#1   2012    AAA       2               0         2        2.5            NaN
#2   2012    BBB       0               1         1        NaN            10
#3   2013    AAA       1               0         1        2.5            NaN
```

Comment: Great! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

here it is:
In your dataframe, the waiting time must be a number be able to use `mean`, see `as.numeric()` to convert it.

```
df = data.frame(c("2012","2012","2012","2013"),
                c("AAA","BBB","AAA","AAA"),
                c("X","Not-serviced","X","Y"),
                c(2,10,3,2.5))

colnames(df) = c("year","type","service_type","waiting_time")

library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(num_serviced = sum(service_type != "Not-serviced"), 
              num_notserviced = sum(service_type =="Not-serviced"),
              avg_wt_serviced = ifelse(service_type != "Not-serviced",mean(waiting_time),0),
              avg_wt_notserviced = ifelse(service_type == "Not-serviced",mean(waiting_time),0)), 
          .(year, type)][, Total := num_serviced + num_notserviced][]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seem to lie in the quoted columns. 
Edit/Added: Because of quotes the colummn is being read as factor variable. See  `class(df$waiting_time)`

Adding this line before computation  gives  the correct answer for me.

```
df$waiting_time<- as.numeric(as.character(df$waiting_time))
```

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure how this is related to the question? I am asking how to create two columns `avg_wt_serviced` and `avg_wt_notserviced` using `data.table`

Comment: OK. It was giving odd mean values for me  both with data.table and dplyr, so I thought that was the issue (which this thing solved). Will look into splitting it to wide format now